# create new matrix based on row values and counting of observations

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, reshape, tidyr

I am trying to create a matrix that captures when people have voted together and how many times they have voted together. However a considerable amount of transforming/shaping my current data is necessary.. any help would be appreciated!

my data currently looks like this:

```
 case <- c("A", "B", "C") 
 id1 <- c(2, 4, 5)
 id2 <- c(1, 2, 3) 
 id3 <- c(4, 3, 5) 
 id4 <- c(3, 4, 2) 
 DF <- as.data.frame(cbind(case,id1,id2,id3,id4)) 
 DF
```

note - The order of in which people (ids) vote does not matter, also not all people vote on all cases.

What I would like my data to look like as a 5x5 matrix:

```
    1  2  3 4  5 
  1 1  1  1 0 0   
  2 1  1  2 2 1 
  3 1  2  1 2 1 
  4 0  2  2 1 1 
  5 0  1  1 1 1
```

Each column is a unique id and each row is a unique id. The values inside the matrix represent the number of times one person voted with another person.

I understand this process might take multiple stages in order to get the voting matrix in the final form I desire. I have tried to create a dataframe where each column is a unique case and each row is a unique id value with the melt function in the reshape package with no luck! Thanks for reading!

Comment: Use `DF <- data.frame(case,id1,id2,id3,id4)` to define your data. Otherwise you end up with a character matrix which is just difficult to work with.

Comment: `crossprod(table(melt(DF)[2:3]))`